# How are objects for the data definition called?

Tags: oop, ddl

In database design the following terms are often used:

- DDL: Data Definition Language
- DML: Data Modification Language

In the object oriented world the following term is commonly used:

- DAO: Data Access Objects

Data Access Objects are using the Data Modification Language to access the data.

What is the term for objects, which are using the Data Definition Language to modify the structure of the data?

I tried to search for DDO but this does not seem to be a commonly used term. What is the right term?

Answer (score 0):

The DAO are used to access the data both to read it and to modify it. You can't find a separate term as it is used for both.

Data structure modifications are usually not done that way since it's part of program development not normally done at run time. If it were done then a DAO would be a reasonable place to put it.